# java code for this formula ( Android App)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, formula

I want to convert this formula to java code for eclipse.
The formula is:

```
n = - ln[R - (0.008 * t)] + [4 -(3.5 * R)] * k
```

Comment: Well, the code required is the exact same formula but with [] replaced with () and starting with double n = ...

Answer (score 2):

The only non-trivial part of the conversion is the natural log, "ln". See [Math.log](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#log-double-).

The rest is just a matter of replacing [] with (), keeping the nesting.

Answer (score 0):

```
int k = 1; // k value
int t = 1; // t value
int R = 1; // R value
double n = -Math.log(R-(0.008*t)) + (4-(3.5*R)) * k;
```

You can replace the k,t and R variables by what you wish. I hope this little code will help you.

Comment: Yes log = ln. look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#log%28double%29).